# Import a C library without git

Tags: swift

Is there a way to include a C library in a Swift project without creating a git repository? That seems to be [the only way explained](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#require-system-libraries) on the Package manager documentation. Starting a git repo just to include some C headers that are already on my computer seems unwieldy.

I tried using a `module.map` file in a module, just like for any pure Swift module, and the C module imports fine, but contains no symbols.

This is what my project looks like:

```
Project
├── Package.swift
└── Sources
    ├── Project
    │   └── main.swift
    ├── The_C_module_i_want
    │   ├── module.modulemap
    │   └── Package.swift (empty, else it won’t compile)
    └── Some_Swift_module
        └── taylor.swift
```

The top level `Package.swift` looks like

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(name: "Project",
                targets   : [
                             Target(name: "Project", 
                                    dependencies: ["Some_Swift_module", 
                                                   "The_C_module_i_want"]),
                             Target(name: "Some_Swift_module"),
                             Target(name: "The_C_module_i_want")
                            ]
                )
```

and the module map looks like this:

```
module The_C_module_i_want {
    header "/usr/local/include/The_C_library/the_c_library.h"
    export *

    link ...
    link ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can always download it as a Zip and include it in your project?

Comment: this question is about including c headers without ever using git repos

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what git has to do with it?

Comment: it’s the only way I found from the [documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#require-system-libraries) to import C code. Importing pure swift modules without git works fine, but the C modules don’t

Comment: The `Package.swift` in `The_C_module_i_want` doesn't make sense. Package.swift is for packages not targets, `The_C_module_i_want` is a target of the package, not a package itself.

Comment: I don't think you can currently do what you want. I mean you could probably pass in compiler flags via `-Xswiftc` etc to locate the module map for the external library (and move that out of your package), but presumably you want to just call `swift build` ... So yes, to externalise that I think you need a separate C package (it could be a local GIT repro though, doesn't have to be hosted ...).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Importing pure swift modules without git works fine". That you can copy the source code into a separate target of your Package and have that build as part of your Package? *That* you can do with C too, copy the `.c` files into the target directory and `.h` files into a headers subdirectory. SPM will create the module for you.

Comment: the empty `Package.swift` is because it would complain about “module has no sources” if it wasn’t there. i don’t understand why Swift needs anything more than `module.map` to use external C code

Comment: I started only recently to work with the Swift package manager and had exactly the same problem. Did you try to ask at the swift-users mailing list?